# How to lock items to Mutiny dock?

Tags: 18.04, mate, dock, mutiny

The dock in Mutiny is the element called launcher in Unity, the bar on the left side with applications icons. In Unity it was possible to "lock to launcher", meaning the icon would stay visible in the launcher, even when the application was not running. In Mutiny it is possible to "pin to dock", which has the same effect. However, when the user logs out Mutiny "forgets" about the items that were pinned.

How can I permanently pin an item to the Mutiny dock, so that it remains in there into the next session?

**Update**: the list of files in the home not owned by my user (as requested by N0rbert):

```
$ sudo find $HOME \! -user $USER -ls 
  8683552      4 drwx------   2 root     root         4096 Dec 25  2017 /home/lads/.cache/dconf
  8664935     12 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root          465 Jul 19 20:40 /home/lads/.dbus/session-bus/24b83445d56047d8bdf7cb11e377e3e8-0
  8665361     12 -rw-------   1 root     root         1708 Aug  1  2017 /home/lads/.android/adbkey
  8665721     12 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root          714 Aug  1  2017 /home/lads/.android/adbkey.pub
  8683526      4 drwx------   2 root     root         4096 Dec 25  2017 /home/lads/.gvfs
  8663854     20 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        11804 Aug 23  2016 /home/lads/.local/share/applications/defaults.list
  8915995      4 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           52 May 25  2017 /home/lads/.mozilla/plugins/libnpjp2.so -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so
```

Comment: I pinned Caja and Meld (by drag-and-drop from dash) on 18.04 LTS, they remain here after reboot. Possible permission issue. Please add output of `sudo find $HOME \! -user $USER -ls` to the question (it will list files owned by other user).